# Can Solidity be use outside of Ethereum?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

Simple question, can you develop and deploy blockchain using solidity?

Can we use solidity outside of Ethereum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solidity was developed specifically for Ethereum and compiles to Ethereum Virtual Machine bytecode, so it can be run only by EVM engines.